# Why isn't my Talos install booting the k8s apiserver, though it otherwise seems functional

Tags: virtual-machines, kubernetes

I've been trying to get Talos up and running on a few VMs using libvirt. Those VMs appear to be launching `etcd` and it's clear from the logs the etcd's are talking to each other, and it's also clear that the controller is running in a loop trying to start things, but one of those things does not appear to be the apiserver, and the things it *is* trying to start are failing because they can't contact the apiserver.

I have verified that I can contact `etcd`, and pull keys out of it. I can even contact it at the configured vip for the system. I'm using 3 control plane VMs. I tried it with just one as well.

Also, `./talosctl -n <control plane node> ls /etc/kubernetes/manifests` reveals that none of the manifests have been put in place.

I'm not sure what information would be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to first check the troubleshooting guide and see what works and what does not working properly yet:
https://www.talos.dev/v1.4/advanced/troubleshooting-control-plane/